# How to blur my hdri?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hdri

There're some videos doing this however its older versions and some nodes don't even exist anymore. Blur is gone and so subtract.

I have no idea how to blur my hdri.

Even tried photoshop but when i put it to blender theres a black line between the 0 and 360 angle

Comment: Its not a duplicate for gods sake. Its for 2.8.1. not 2.7 something.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question directly but will solve your problem. In Photoshop duplicate your unblurred HDRI to another layer so that it is on bottom. use Filter/Offset to offset image 50%. Blur both layers. Offset the offsetted layer back where it was, and erase the sharp borders from the original top layer. Voilà.

Comment: Gonna try it tomorrow thanks.